# How to limit search results in start button?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I use start button to quickly find applications on windows 7. For some applications, i have multiple versions and I have not deleted them yet as it may possibly lead to some sort of dependency issues. But I am sure which version of application I want to use. Can I somehow limit the search results to only show the latest version of applications without having to type the version number ?

Comment: What sort of application allows multiple versions of the same application to be installed?  I can tell you this functionality does not exist within Windows by default.  You would have to turn to third-party software to enable something like this.

Comment: For instance, I use VISit, a visualization software. I have couple of versions of its installed because sometime a newer version fails to open a particular kind of file and I have to use an older version till that bug is fixed. But otherwise I mostly use the latest version.

Comment: Create shortcut to specific versions that indicate the version withn the name "Visit 9", "Visit 8" "Vist ..." then just search for "Vist ..."

Comment: Thank you. This is an option which did not occur to me.